# Angualr jasmine test case - dispatch row click event in mat table row

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am writing test case in angular jasmine-

I have a mat-table with tr as

```
<tr mat-row (click)="click()" *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns">
```

I want to fire this event from jasmine test case like below but it is not working

```
fit('should open new tab', () => {
      const spy = spyOn(window, 'open').and.callThrough();
      let row = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('tbody tr');
      
      row.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
      //click event
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**querySelectorAll** returns [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), so try to access at least the first element in the list(just add `[0]` after querySelectorAll()) and see if test works.
Then modify the selector if you need to click on a certain row